# ubuntu - cannot start application - Could not create transient scope

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04
Today, i cannot start many applications (Sublime, whatapps, ...)
I try to search on google, but don't have any solution to resolve this issue. 
Please help me! I don't want to re-install my ubuntu :(

```
May 11 09:46:23 ndt-55555 dbus-daemon[9663]: [session uid=1000 pid=9663] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.19' (uid=1000 pid=9732 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 11 09:46:23 ndt-55555 dbus-daemon[9663]: [session uid=1000 pid=9663] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.19' (uid=1000 pid=9732 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 11 09:46:23 ndt-55555 dbus-daemon[9663]: [session uid=1000 pid=9663] Activating service name='org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.19' (uid=1000 pid=9732 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 11 09:46:23 ndt-55555 dbus-daemon[9663]: [session uid=1000 pid=9663] Activating service name='org.gnome.Characters.BackgroundService' requested by ':1.19' (uid=1000 pid=9732 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 11 09:46:23 ndt-55555 dbus-daemon[9663]: [session uid=1000 pid=9663] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider'
May 11 09:46:23 ndt-55555 dbus-daemon[9663]: [session uid=1000 pid=9663] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
May 11 09:46:23 ndt-55555 dbus-daemon[9663]: [session uid=1000 pid=9663] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Characters.BackgroundService'
May 11 09:46:23 ndt-55555 dbus-daemon[9663]: [session uid=1000 pid=9663] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider'
May 11 09:46:23 ndt-55555 nautilus[11712]: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
May 11 09:46:24 ndt-55555 sublime-text_subl.desktop[11766]: env: ‘/snap/bin/sublime-text.subl’: No such file or directory
May 11 09:46:24 ndt-55555 gnome-shell[9732]: Could not create transient scope for PID 11766: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 11766 does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to remove & install gnome-software again. **It's resolved**.

```
sudo apt autoremove gnome-software
sudo apt install gnome-software
```